# The property of Hölder continuous density function

Tags: statistics, holder-spaces, nonparametric-statistics

I am reading the [article](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Ethanh-mai.pham-ngoc/HoangPhamRivoirardTran.pdf) but I don't understand some lines in page 10.

> First, assumptions on the density $h$ are needed. Of course, since $h$ is the density of a symmetric probability distribution on $[0,1]$, it satisfies $\int h(x) d x=1$ and $\int x h(x) d x=1 / 2$. For the proofs, we will also need the following condition.
>
> Assumption 1. The function $h$ is of class $\mathcal{C}^\beta$ on $[0,1]$, for some $\beta>3$ : the function $h$ is $[\beta]$ times differentiable (where $[\beta]$ is the largest integer smaller than $\beta$ ) and the derivative of order $[\beta]$ is $\beta-[\beta]$ Hölder continuous.
>
> Moreover, we assume that there exists a positive integer $v_0 \geq 2$ such that for all $k \in\left\{0, \ldots, v_0\right\}$, $h^{(k)}(0)=0$
>
> Under Assumption $1, h$ can take positive values only on $(0,1)$, and the function $g$ introduced previously is supported on $\mathbb{R}_{-}$.

I don't understand the reason why under assumption 1, $h$ must take positive values only on (0, 1).
Thank you for reading my question and your kind support

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Could you please suggest me some suitable titles? @Shaun

Comment: I'm not in a position to do so. However, a title need to describe the question enough that a user can determine whether they are interested and can help, by reading it

Comment: Thank you a lot. I changed the new title @Shaun

Comment: You're welcome. That's much better!

Answer (score 0):

$h$ is defined on $[0,1]$, so saying that it "can take positive values only on $(0,1)$" is the same as saying that $h(0) = h(1) = 0$.

The relevant part of the assumption is this one :

> Moreover, we assume that there exists a positive integer $v_0\ge 2$
> such that $h^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k\in\{0,\ldots,v_0\}$

This tells you in particular that $h(0)=0$. Then, because $h$ [is symmetric about its mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution#Properties), it follows that $h(1) = h(1/2 + 1/2) = h(0) = 0 $, exactly as the authors claim.

(Remark : this had nothing to do with Hölder continuity of $h$ !)

Comment: Yes, I used to think that h(1) = h(0) = 0 but I don't know why this property is the same as saying h can take positive values only on (0;1). What's going on if h(1/2) = 0 ? Could you please explain more? Thank you for your kind support @StratosFair

Comment: @Pipnap : The assertion "$h$ takes positive values only on $(0,1)$" can be restated mathematically as $$``\forall x \in \mathbb R,\ \ h(x) > 0 \implies x \in (0,1)"$$ 
It is not incompatible with the fact that there exist some values of $x\in (0,1)$ for which $h(x)=0$, as it just means that if $h(x)$ is positive, then $x$ is **necessarily** in $(0,1)$. It does **not** say that $h(x)$ is positive for **all** $x\in (0,1)$. Get it ?

Comment: oh, I understood. Thank you so much.